# Magento 2 Visible Google Recaptcha validation for Newsletter

Tags: magento2, captcha, recaptcha, mageplaza

I have downloaded mageplaza's free recaptcha module from here:

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-google-recaptcha

However I want to show "I am not a robot" Visible recaptcha for my newsletter at footer.

The issue is if I select Invisible from admin the "Invisible Recatpcha" is working fine without any error. But I am unable to validating the "Visible Recaptcha" like "I am not a robot". If I click directly on subscribe button with email, it reloads the page without validating the captcha.

Thank You.